Creating GraalVM native image with Maven failed - "Cannot find 'option' in class org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.config.agent.AgentOptionsConfiguration"
I'm following the Getting Started with Maven Plugin for GraalVM Native Image and Maven plugin for GraalVM Native Image building to create the native image for my Java application on my Windows 11.
PS E:\zipper\OneDrive\remoteAccess\dev\p3s\p3sclient> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\NetBeans-22\netbeans\java\maven
Java version: 22.0.2, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: C:\Progra~1\Java\graalvm-community-openjdk-22.0.2+9.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

mvn clean package and mvn -Pnative -Dagent exec:exec@java-agent went fine and mvn -DskipTests=true -Pnative -Dagent package failed, complaining Cannot find 'option' in class org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.config.agent.AgentOptionsConfiguration.
Here is the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <name>p3sclient</name>
    <groupId>p3s</groupId>
    <artifactId>p3sclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>p3s</groupId>
        <artifactId>p3s</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <native.maven.plugin.version>0.10.2</native.maven.plugin.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.11.0</junit.jupiter.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <imageName>p3sclient</imageName>
        <mainClass>p3sclient.Main</mainClass>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.formdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatlaf</artifactId>
            <version>0.46</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>p3s</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- annotationProcessorPaths requires maven-compiler-plugin version 3.5 or higher -->
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
                            <artifactId>picocli-codegen</artifactId>
                            <version>4.7.5</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <fallback>false</fallback>
                            <agent>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <options>
                                    <enableExperimentalPredefinedClasses>true</enableExperimentalPredefinedClasses>
                                    <enableExperimentalUnsafeAllocationTracing>
                                        true
                                    </enableExperimentalUnsafeAllocationTracing>
                                    <trackReflectionMetadata>true</trackReflectionMetadata>
                                </options>
                            </agent>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>java-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                        <classpath/>
                                        <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>${project.build.directory}/${imageName}</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>

and here is the error information:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.10.2:merge-agent-files (test-native) on project p3sclient: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.10.2:merge-agent-files for parameter option: Cannot find 'option' in class org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.config.agent.AgentOptionsConfiguration -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.10.2:merge-agent-files (test-native) on project p3sclient: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.10.2:merge-agent-files for parameter option: Cannot find 'option' in class org.graalvm.buildtools.maven.config.agent.AgentOptionsConfiguration
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
... ... ...

For all the detailed outputs of mvn, please see here: https://github.com/zipper01/Creating-GraalVM-native-image-with-Maven-failed/blob/main/Creating%20GraalVM%20native%20image%20with%20Maven%20failed.txt

Are you using a suggested combination of JVM, Java version and libraries?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Java version: 22.0.2, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: C:\Progra~1\Java\graalvm-community-openjdk-22.0.2+9.1

It does not look like the build toolsplugin supports Java 22 as of 0.10.2 according to https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/index.html#changelog
I would suggest using Java 21 instead.

Thank you for the suggestion. I changed to Java 21.0.4 and it resulted same error.
